# Excel 2013 VBA - Runtime error 9: Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and did run into a problem I can't seem to find a solution to on my own -> so Your help is much appreciated :).

I'm getting "Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range" when attempting to run following code:

```
Dim i as Long, l as Long, x as Long, y as Long, z as Long, lastrow as Long

   '..some unrelevant code
   x = 2

   For y = 1 To lastrow Step 2: For i = y To lastrow Step 2: For z = 0 To 1

   '..do stuff

   If z = 0 Then

        Dim datarange As Variant
        Dim myvar As Double
        Dim comp As Double
        Dim lrow As Long
        Dim lcol As Long

        l = 0
        lrow = x
        datarange = Range("k" & x & ":" & "ab" & x + 1).Value
        For lcol = 11 To 28
            myvar = datarange(lrow, lcol)
            comp = datarange(lrow + 1, lcol)
            If comp > 1 Then
                If myvar > 1 Then
                l = l + 1
                End If
            Else: l = l + 1
            End If
        Next

   End If

   x = x + 1

   Next: Next: Next

   '..etc
```

I got to this point after implementing the code-part with grey background in effort to include following knowledge into my project: http://blogs.office.com/2008/10/03/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-scan-a-large-range-in-excel/ (third point "Use a variant type variable").

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what line do you get the error on? You aren't declaring datarange correctly if you intend it to be an array you should declare it with `Dim datarange() As Variant`.

Comment: Row and column indexes into `datarange` both start at 1, and run to #rows_in_datarange and #cols_in_datarange respectively,  since it has its own coordinate system which is independent of its position on the worksheet.

Comment: When you set `datarange`,  you do not use the `CurrentRegion` member of the range object as the sample code you link to does.

Comment: Where do you initialize `lastrow`?

Comment: Thanks for your blazing fast responses guys :)! ..got it to run. Especially thanking Tim for pointing this out.. was wondering about it but dind't find an answer through googling a bit.

Comment: @collapsar how do I find out the line in which the error occurs? Also, do you say the guy in the link I posted used wrong syntax in his example code? ("Dim DataRange As Variant ")

Comment: No, not at all. Just pointing out mismatches between the reference and your adaptation.

Comment: @collapsar Ah okay.. well I will understand it at some point. I guess ^^.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll pardon the expression, you've two-stepped out of the bounds of the array:)

The index numbers of the dataRange array are different then their row/column numbers. If you go to VB Editor, View, and the Locals window as you are stepping through the code (F8), you will see that the array is 1 to 2 by 1 to 18.